# Nginx to serve static page before dynamic

Tags: php, nginx

I want to serve static HTML files with NGINX, but if the file is missing, it should load a PHP file instead and PHP should handle the content.

I've been testing several combinations of `try_files`, but I can't get my head around it. I have a dummy PHP app that looks like this:

```
./
../
dynamic.php
index.php
static/
static/static.html
```

Then I have a small PHP code on index like this:

```
<?php

$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$pattern = '/^\/(.*)\.html$/';

$matches = [];

$results = preg_match($pattern, $path, $matches);

if (count($matches) > 0) {
    if ($matches[1] == "dynamic") {
        require 'dynamic.php';
    } else {
        echo "Not found!";
    }
} else {
    echo "Index page!";
}
```

The results of browsing to each page should be:

```
http://foo.bar/             - Loads index.php
http://foo.bar/static.html  - Loads static/static.html
http://foo.bar/dynamic.html - Loads index.php & PHP requires dynamic.php
http://foo.bar/baz.html     - Loads index.php with "not found" message
```

This is what I got in the NGINX config file:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .foo.bar *.foo.bar;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/foo.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/foo.error.log;

    root /var/www/foo;
    index index.php;

    location / {
        # Trying with 'try_files' here. No success.
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-foo.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

I've been trying repeatedly and evidently utterly failing with this line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/static /index.php;
```

I am missing something. Help?

Comment: Isn't it possible in your case to do some URL rewriting but handle the displayed page using PHP all the time ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would use your static directory as document root. This ensures that nobody can execute `/dynamic.php` directly, however, it will be forwarded to your `index.php` by the named location block `@php`.

> This configuration example is untested!

```
server {
    index       index.php;
    root        /var/www/foo/static;
    server_name foo.bar *.foo.bar;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @php;
    }

    location @php {
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-foo.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/foo/index.php;
    }
}
```

1. You don't need the `listen` directive if it only contains 80 since this is the default.
2. The `server_name`s should not contain a leading dot.
3. The `$uri` always contains the requested URI including the leading slash (e.g. `/static.html`) and nginx will prefix them with the document root upon invocation of `try_files` (e.g. `/var/www/foo/static.html`). Hence, you need to set your `static` directory before the `$uri` (e.g. `/static$uri` becomes `/var/www/foo/static/static.html`).
4. You don't need `fastcgi_split_path_info` because you are not using that feature.
5. Your `try_files` in your PHP location makes it impossible for nginx to properly forward things. A request for `/dynamic.html` does not end on `.php`, hence, `try_files` always fails.

Comment: Either `.example.com` or `example.com *.example.com`; usage of the combination of both makes no sense.

Comment: Actually you cannot add the `try_files` inside of the `@php` location because no `dynamic.html` file exists in there and nginx would not forward the request to php-fpm. However, I changed the configuration to account for the issue you mentioned.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your point 2. I thought you were saying that one should never use a server name with a leading dot. I totally agree with your analysis

Comment: Yeah, lets forget I mentioned it :-)

Answer (score 7):

There are a number of ways of hiding the `static` directory from the URL. For example, manipulating `root`, clever use of `try_files` or a `rewrite`.

Possibly the most obvious is this:

```
root /var/www/foo;

location / {
    root /var/www/foo/static;
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ { ... }
```

so that `nginx` looks in the `static` folder for normal files, but the parent folder for `.php` files.

What you were trying to achieve was something like this:

```
root /var/www/foo;

location / {
    try_files /static$uri /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ { ... }
```

which will prefix `/static` to any URI before testing for existence. The `/index.php` must be the last element as it required processing in a different location. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mistake I made, but your suggestion is also not working. When attempting to go to `/`, I am redirected to `//static/` (with two forward-slashes) and when attempting to go to `/static.html` I am redirected to `/static/`. =/

Comment: @Apollo I cannot reproduce your failure mode but I did need to add a `try_files` statement to the first example.

Comment: @Apollo, which of the two examples in this answer did you use to get the failure described in your comment?

Comment: @Richard, using the first example, `foo.bar/` does work, but the URI changes to `foo.bar//static/`; `foo.bar/static.html` redirects to index and changes the URI to `foo.bar/static/`; `foo.bar/dynamic.html` works; `foo.bar/baz.html` yields a blank page.

Comment: @Richard, using the second example, results are the same. Thanks!

Comment: @Apollo please try `try_files static/$uri index.php =404;` for the second Richards' example.

Comment: @yergo Thanks, but now something a bit bizarre is happening: now all addresses are resulting in index.php being served as a download file with different file names. xD

Comment: @yergo just to clarify: I am usng `/index.php` with a forward slash. If I remove it, the behaviour is the same as before. Strange.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the specific example case you have given, the configuration below will return the results you listed.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name .foo.bar *.foo.bar;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/foo.access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/foo.error.log;

    root /var/www/foo;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm-foo.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~ /static {
        rewrite ^/static\.html$ /static/ last;
        index static.html;
    }
    location ~ / {
        rewrite ^ /index.php last;
    }
```

That is ...

```
http://foo.bar/             - Loads index.php
http://foo.bar/static.html  - Loads static/static.html
http://foo.bar/dynamic.html - Loads index.php & PHP requires dynamic.php
http://foo.bar/baz.html     - Loads index.php with "not found" message
```